# Can I dispose an using block after outer try/catch catch an exception?

Tags: c#, try-catch, using, idisposable

```
try
{
    using (Ctx.Push("going to run func1"))
    {
        func1();

        using (Ctx.Push("going to run func2"))
        {
            throw new Exception("something wrong before running func2");
            func2();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(Ctx.GetStack());

    // actual output: { }
    // output I want to get: { "going to run func1", "going to run func2" }

}
```

Please consider the code above.

Supposed that `Ctx.Push` is a static class method which `Push` the message into a context stack and `Pop` that message from the stack when disposing. Which means I can get the context stack within these `using` block as they have not been disposed. However, if there is any exception thrown within these `using` block and I will lost that context stack as the context stack will be disposed before reaching the `catch` block.

May I know if there any way to logically achieve something like **deferring the Dispose() action after outer exception caught?**

- Adding try/catch inside every `using` block is not a solution for me as I don't really need it, this makes the code so messy.
- Calling `Ctx.push()` and `Dispose()` manually is not a soultion for me as well. Since it is quite danger when other co-worker in the project forget to `Dispose()` it eventually.

I know that it may be impossible. Any other approach/solution would be welcome as long as I can solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `using` block is just a short hand for `try { } finally { resource.Dispose(); }`, so of course you cannot stop using `using` **and** not call `Dispose()` manually, as you'd never call Dispose then

Comment: Disposal doesn't necessarily mean that something is unusable; *finalization* does. Is `Ctx` a class that you control? If so, please post it. The information it accumulates could be retained for your call to `GetStack` but there's no way to know without seeing the code.

Comment: Actually, you've conflated the individual `IDisposable` instances that `Push` returns with the static information that `Ctx` maintains, either in the implementation or just your understanding of it. You're not disposing the static part.

Comment: Should `Dispose` be both pop-ing the message and disposing the object?

Comment: I would opine that `Dispose` *is* the "Pop" method and therefore no public method named "Pop" should exist so it can't be misused.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The library that I am using is log4net, you may refer to **Context Stacks** in https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html. I can log anything inside `using` block. However, if an uncaught exception throw outside the scope, I can no longer get back the context stack inside `using` as it has been popped out already.